# How to make a undo/redo function

Tags: javascript, undo-redo

I want to add a `undo/redo` function in my script. I have looked around and see some suggestions, most of them recommended to use `command pattern`.

The function must work over one page - after a reload of the page the function must able to `redo/undo` the last things.

I don't know how command pattern works, I think about to create a object, to store the a name of the function, the old and the new value - but I'm not sure if this is a efficient way to do this or not.

Maybe somebody could give me a small example how the code for a `undo/redo` function should look.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's 2 common ways of implementing undo/redo, both of them very well established and defined [*Design Patterns.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)

The [**Memento Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern) and the [**Command Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

#### The [**Memento Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern), where you capture the whole *current [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science))*.

> The memento pattern is a software design pattern that exposes the
> private internal state of an object. One example of how this can be
> used is to restore an object to its previous state (undo via
> rollback), another is versioning, another is custom serialization.

It's easy to implement, but memory-inefficient since you need to store similar copies of the whole state.

#### The [**Command Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), where you capture ***commands/actions*** that affect the state; the *current action* and it's *inverse action*.

Or you know.. you can be more specific and just call it the **Inverse Action** method. Or Newtons 3rd law. Every action must have an equal and opposite reaction. Or *undo-by-reversal*.

This is harder to implement since for for each undoable action in your application you must explicitly code it's inverse action. Every time you build a feature you must think a bit. How would you reverse it. Is it even theoretically reversible?
It's a pain in the ass but it's far more memory-efficient since you only store the actions that affect the state.

My flippant advice is this:

If you're building a little tool thingy for your own use and you just want a quick and dirty way to get this over with, go for the Memento Pattern. Easy to implement and it just works. Maybe you just want to allow your user to undo some choices in a user flow? The Memento Pattern is the perfect choice.

Now, if you're building an undo mechanism for a sophisticated system with a certain degree of complexity and above you're gonna *have to* go for the Command Pattern; it's almost a given, otherwise you'll run out of memory before you know it.

I'll elaborate further:

### The Memento Pattern

Before an action is applied, you take a snapshot of the current state and save it into an array. That snapshot is the *Memento*.

If the user wants to undo, you simply `pop` the last memento and apply it. The program returns to the state it was before the last action was applied.

This pattern is memory intensive; each memento is relatively large since it captures the *whole* current state.

But it's also the easiest to implement since you don't need to explicitly code all cases and their inverse actions that you need to in the Command Pattern (see below).

Here's a stupidly easy example:

```js
const mementos = []
const input = document.querySelector('input')

function saveMemento() {
  mementos.push(input.value)
}

function undo() {
  const lastMemento = mementos.pop()
   
  input.value = lastMemento ? lastMemento : input.value
}
```

```html
<h4> Type some characters and hit Undo </h4>
<input onkeydown="saveMemento()" value="Hello World"/>
<button onclick="undo()">Undo</button>
```

Notice that this is *all you need* regardless of the operation your user is doing. You don't have to start planning for what the user might do so you can explicitly code it's inverse action. You just save the state and no matter of the user does, when you revert to the old state, it's done. Amazing... If it wasn't for the fact you're saving ever-increasing copies of state in-memory.

### The Command Pattern

For each action the user takes, you also save a corresponding *inverse* action/command. For example, each time you add character in a textbox, you save the inverse function; which is to delete the character at that position.

If the user wants to undo, you pop the last inverse action/command and apply it.

```js
const commands = []
const input = document.querySelector('input')

function saveCommand(e) {
  commands.push({
    // the action is also saved for implementing redo, which
    // is not implemented in this example.
    action: { type: 'add', key: e.key, index: input.selectionStart },
    inverse: { type: 'remove', index: input.selectionStart }
  })
}

function undo() {
  let value = input.value.split('')
  const lastCommand = commands.pop()
 
  if (!lastCommand) return
    
  switch (lastCommand.inverse.type) {
    case 'remove':
      value.splice(lastCommand.inverse.index, 1)
      break;      
  }
  
  input.value = value.join('')
}
```

```html
<h4> Type some characters and hit Undo </h4>
<input onkeydown="saveCommand(event)" value="Hello World"/>
<button onclick="undo()">Undo</button>
```

This snippet is obviously a hyper-oversimplification; I've took care of **just one case**, when adding characters. What if the user is removing characters? Styling them? You can see where it goes.

Pick your poison.

A sophisticated undo system is probably gonna be using a little bit of both. If I'm building Photoshop and my user is moving the image 1px to the left, I'll could take a Memento of the current coordinates of that image, instead of the whole canvas.

It all depends though on your use case.

A sufficiently complex system is also going to need *bottom-up undo*. Undo managers in the items themselves, hooked up to Undo Managers that become more global as you come up the abstraction layers. But that's much too blah blah for the purposes of this question.

Hope this helps

Comment: like you wrote i think command pattern are the better choice. Is it possible to make me a little script to see, explain and understand how this should be looking for in js-code?

Comment: I'm writing them now, but be advised that they are  a gross oversimplification of the formal patterns.

Comment: ok - could you give me a example for the command pattern too? so i can start to learn, did this function works after a pagereload?

Comment: Depending on the type of application, a *"Memento of commands"* might be better. For instance in graphic tools, you can't always have an inverse command, and saving each full state would drain the memory in no time. So storing all the commands and calling them all in sequence on undo is the way to go.

Comment: @Kaiido Stellar, didn't know about that. Basically you're replaying all the commands until you reach the current state - 1, is that correct?

Comment: .Yes that's it.

Comment: "Memento of commands" is a great idea! I would suggest a rename though to avoid confusion - I initially confused it to be a list of commands that would help you undo, step-by-step from present to the past. Instead, I'd just call it "command history", and explain: store your starting position (original image in photoshop), and save each command (edits). To Undo, start from the beginning and replay all commands except 1."

Comment: @BenButterworth This is a neat idea, but may run into performance issues if some of the commands take a long time to complete (i.e. Photoshop filters being applied, etc).  In such case, it may be wise to save snapshots of the entire project periodically, especially after long-running commands, thus giving you another starting point to avoid waiting on long commands to complete.